# Typeorm getRepository mockImplementation returning mocked findOne method

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using nestjs with typeOrm
This is the method I want to test.

PropertyBuilder.ts

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm'
...

export class PropertyBuilder extends BasicEntityBuilder<PropertyDto, Property> {
  async onUpdatedOwner_id(entity: any, dtoField: string, propertyDto: PropertyDto) {
    if (dtoField !== 'owner_id') {
      throw new Error('dtoField is not valid')
    }
    entity[dtoField] = await getRepository(User).findOne({ id: propertyDto.owner_id })
  }
}
```

PropertyBuilder.spec.ts

```
import ...

describe('PropertyBuilder', () => {
  let userRepository: Repository<User>

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          useClass: Repository,
        },
      ],
    }).compile()

    userRepository = module.get(getRepositoryToken(User))
  })

  describe('onUpdatedOwner_id', () => {
    it('should set owner_id field with User object', () => {
      const expected: any = { name: 'user' }
      const entity: Property = new Property()
      const dto: PropertyDto = new PropertyDto()
      jest.spyOn(userRepository, 'findOne').mockResolvedValue(expected)
      new PropertyBuilder(Property).onUpdatedOwner_id(entity, 'owner_id', dto)
      expect(entity.owner_id).toBe(expected)
    })
  })
})
```

The test fails with `(node:952986) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.`

I know I shouldn't provide anything...
I tried with

```
describe('onUpdatedOwner_id', () => {
    it('should set owner_id field with User object', () => {
      const expected: any = { name: 'user' }
      const entity: Property = new Property()
      const dto: PropertyDto = new PropertyDto()

      const getRepositoryMock = jest.fn() as jest.MockedFunction<typeof getRepository>
      getRepositoryMock.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return { findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(expected) }
      })

      jest.spyOn(userRepository, 'findOne').mockResolvedValue(expected)
      new PropertyBuilder(Property).onUpdatedOwner_id(entity, 'owner_id', dto)
      expect(entity.owner_id).toBe(expected)
    })
  })
```

but it doesn't work because the mockImplementation it's not compatible with the signature of getRepository

```
Argument of type '() => { findOne: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(entityClass: EntityTarget<unknown>, connectionName?: string) => Repository<unknown>'.
```

what is the correct way to test my method?

Answer (score 0):

You're mocking the Nest provider for `getRepositoryToken(User)` (what's used under the hood of `@InjectRepository(User)`, but not TypeORM's implementation of `getRepository` which you're making direct use of in `PropertyBuilder`. To mock a package directly with jest, you should do something like

```js
jest.mock('typeorm', () => ({
  getRepository: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(expected)
})
```

which will end up getting hoisted to the top of the file and ran before any TypeORM imports, so that this can be used instead. You can add whatever other methods you need to to the `({})` return as well.